# Speech Recognition script not working

Tags: speech-recognition, ubuntu-12.04

I have this speech recognition script which
records audio input and sends to Google's
speech recognition servers and receives the 
results and shows them on Ubuntu terminal.
But I am failing to make it work.
My guess is that Google has made a change 
or something that is why it is not working
anymore.
I need this script for a voice based web 
browser project.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash



results=6

if [ "$1" == "-r" ];then
    results="$2"
fi


echo "Recording... Please press ^C a few seconds after finishing."
rec -r 16000 -b 16 -c 1 test.wav > /dev/null 2>&1
echo
echo "Recording finished!"
sox test.wav test.flac gain -n -5 silence 1 5 2% > /dev/null 2>&1
echo "Now uploading to google's speech recognition servers."
echo
echo "This may take a bit..."
a=$(curl \
  --data-binary @test.flac \
  --header 'Content-type: audio/x-flac; rate=16000' \
  'https://www.google.com/speech-api/v1/recognize?xjerr=1&client=chromium&pfilter=2&lang=en-US&maxresults='$results'' 2>/dev/null)
#echo "Done! Parsing results..."
echo
b=$(echo "$a" |egrep -o "\"confidence\":[^}]*" |sed 's/"confidence"://')
c=$(qalc $b \* 100 | egrep -o "=.*" |sed 's/= //' |sed 's/\.\([0-9]\)*/\.\1/')

echo "Done, results below :)"
echo
echo "Confidence in results = ${c}%"
echo "$a" | egrep -o "\"utterance\":\"[^\"]*\"" |sed 's/"utterance":"//;s/"//'|nl
```

Here is a sample incomplete output:

```
john@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ ./test.bash
Recording... Please press ^C a few seconds after finishing.
^C
Recording finished!
Now uploading to google's speech recognition servers.

This may take a bit...
```

After that it is not showing anything.
To see how this script works go to this link:
[LINK](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uM2Yb-PwP6o)

Please help me to find the error.
Information:I am using Ubuntu12.04 in a VMware WS.

Comment: what is the value of $a that you are getting?

Comment: The results.Have you been able to successfully 
run the script?

Comment: I am getting error 500 Internal Server error

Comment: And I have run  the script in rhel6. 'qalc' replaced with 'bc'

Comment: So, what's the solution?
I don't see any way of sending a personal message in stackoverflow. So, if you have a profile in any social networking site give the link in a comment.We won't get any solution in this speed.We need to discuss more.If we finally get a solution I will post that here.

Comment: ok first lets discuss what is the value google api is returning. I am getting error 500 Internal Server Error. echo $a and tell me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that your audio files are too long. I believe that the Google api is limited to files that are less than 3 seconds long.

Comment: 3 seconds might be too short. I tried uploading several 10 seconds long audio files. Some can be recognized. However, there has no any doc from Google talking about the audio duration limit.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to split your bash script into two pieces for debugging purpose. You'd better to prepare a valid FLAC audio file (sampled in 16K Hz) and send it to Google to verify that your core part works. If your plan is just using Google ASR, you may consider directly using [this Python 3.0 solution](https://bitbucket.org/happyalu/py_google_asr)